# How to set a time interval in Time picker

Tags: android

I want to set a time interval of 15 minute in time picker. I have Done it through onTimeChangeListener but it not showing the non focused value in same interval which does not give the good user experience. Can anybody tell me how to change the all value of picker in interval?